# Add delay function on post jquery

Tags: jquery, post, delay

I am adding a delay function on button link

```
<button type='button' onclick="SubmitFormTab_1(event);" class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd tab1_btn btn_wait' name="next_<?php echo $Result_Q[1]->id;?>" id="<?php echo $Result_Q[1]->id;?>" disabled>
      Next
         <span class="btn-label">
            <i class="now-ui-icons arrows-1_minimal-right"></i>
         </span>
      <img src="../../assets/loader-ajax.gif" id="ques_tab1-loader" style="display: none;"/>
</button>
```

code

```
function SubmitFormTab_1(event) {
    var qid = $("#qid2").val();
    var submitid = event.target.id;
    var options = [];
    $("input[name='2[]']:checked").each(function () {
        options.push($(this).val());
    });

    delay(function () {
        $("#ques_tab1-loader").show();
        $.post("fn_wizard_submit.php?submitid=" + submitid, {
                qid: qid,
                options: options
            },

            function (data) {
                $("#ques_tab1-loader").hide();
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
    }, 3000);
}
```

I am tried that when event is generate then delay function is start and also show a loader on button and when delay function is end then loader is hide but its not working and record is not save to database

Comment: What code / library are you using for your `delay()` function?

Comment: use `setTimeout()` instead of `delay()`

Comment: Also: move `$("#ques_tab1-loader").show();` outside the delay/setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use setTimeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

you can read documentation.
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Thank u for ur help... :)